# how to hidden virtual keyboard in android after unfocused an editext

Tags: android, android-edittext, onfocus, virtual-keyboard

I got a simple question, but I can not find it anywhere after a while searching around the internet. Hope that I will get the answer here.

I have an edittext. Every time when this edittext is focused, the virtual keyboard is displayed. However, if I clicked to somewhere else different from the edittext, I suppose that the keyboard will be hidden. But it did not. I do not know if there is any event like isUnfocus or something similar for the edittext so that I can hide the virtual keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" inside <Activity /> in manifest XML.                                                                    <activity
            android:name="Activity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

Answer (score 2):

Add this line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

to your *AndroidManifeast.xml* `<Activity></Activity>` tag. It will hide keyboard when click anywhere in screen if keyboard is visible.

Answer (score 1):

just added setOnFocusChangeListener to Edittext , .

```
EditText editTextProfileName = (EditText) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);

            editTextProfileName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                      if (!hasFocus) {
                            hideKeyboard();
                        }
                }

                private void hideKeyboard() {
                    if (editTextProfileName != null) {
                        InputMethodManager imanager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imanager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextProfileName.getWindowToken(), 0);

                    }

                }
            });
```